# Why am i Getting NullReferenceException when trying to create a HealthPack in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok guys and gals I'm having an issue again with some code.  Basically once I start and it attempts to create a Health Pack it's throwing an error that:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
HealthSpawnerScript.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/HealthSpawnerScript.cs:31)

below is the code i'm running.  The gameobject PlayerController houses a method used to return Player Health named PlayerHealth().  In awake I set playerController to find the script and method I'm after.  Then in update i'm trying to call the method and assign it to a variable for use in the script later.  I know this should be simple but i'm having a brain fart guys.

```
public PlayerController playerController;
private int healthHolder;

void OnAwake()
{
    playerController = GameObject.Find ("PlayerHealth").GetComponent<PlayerController> ();

}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    //set healthExist to false to indicate no health packs exist on game start
    healthExist = false;

    //playerController = GameObject.Find ("PlayerHealth").GetComponent<PlayerController> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    healthHolder = playerController.PlayerHealth();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Unity callback function named `OnAwake`. You are likely looking for the [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) function.

If that is fixed and your problem is still there, you have to seperate your code into pieces and find out what's failing.

```
playerController = GameObject.Find ("PlayerHealth").GetComponent<PlayerController> ();
```

should be changed to

```
void Awake()
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("PlayerHealth");
    if (obj == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to find PlayerHealth GameObject");
        return;
    }

    playerController = obj.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    if (playerController == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("No PlayerController script is attached to obj");
    }
}
```

So, if `GameObject.Find("PlayerHealth")` fails, that means there is no GameObject with that name in the scene. Please check the spellings.

If `obj.GetComponent<PlayerController>();` fails, there is no script called `PlayerController` that is attached to the `PlayerHealth` GameObject. Simplify your problem!

Comment: Not quite what I needed but I figured it out, I was calling the method PlayerHealth attached to PlayerController rather than locating the actual object which would be PlayerShip that had the script PlayerController on it.

Comment: Ok. How about the `OnAwake` function? That was correct?